# in R output shows top and bottom 5 rows of data

Tags: r

I have applied the following row of code to my data:

```
dcast.data.table(melt(setDT(data), id="No.", measure=data[1,11:12])
```

which returns exactly the following:

```
         No.  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
  1:   1 NA NA NA NA NA NA  7 NA  9 NA NA
  2:   2 NA  2 NA NA  5 NA NA NA NA NA NA
  3:   3 NA NA NA  4  5 NA NA NA NA NA NA
  4:   4  1 NA NA NA  5 NA NA NA NA NA NA
  5:   5 NA NA NA  4  5 NA NA NA NA NA NA
 ---                                     
757: 757 NA  2 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 10 NA
758: 758 NA  2  3 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
759: 759 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  8 NA NA 11
760: 760 NA NA  3 NA NA  6 NA NA NA NA NA
761: 761 NA NA  3  4 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Probably a really basic and possibly stupid question, but how would I get to view all of the data?

Comment: Why do you want to look at 761 rows of data? That doesn't seem useful. You should look at data summaries and appropriate plots instead.

Comment: That is just the behaviour of `print.data.table`. Use `print.data.frame` explicitly if you want that behaviour.

Comment: @Roland, I find it sometimes useful to look on data in order to identify stuff that you could have missed in summary, especially if your data set is so small. A good example is Adwords search queries report.

Comment: `print(DT, n=nrow(DT))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In these cases I typically wrap the data.table in `as.data.frame` and send to console, which will print all the data by default.

Comment: This is wasteful. Just do `print.data.frame(DT)`. A data.table inherits class data.frame.

Comment: What advantage do you have in sending tens of thousands rows into the console? Are you able to understand what you see? If your data is small, `View` is much better, if it is huge and you still want to send it to console, why would you change the class? Just use `print.data.frame`.

Comment: @Roland Thanks for that comment, I can see now that `as.data.frame` is wasteful.

Comment: Thank you very much. I agree that this data set is difficult to look at and in fact is not how I want to look the data. But as I am trying to learn R wondered about this behaviour and couldn't resolve it without your kind help. What I really want to achieve is a table showing when each number occurs according to date i.e days ago as columns and the numbers as row names. Still a long way off achieving this goal, mind you. Thanks for the help

Comment: No need. `print(DT, n=nrow(DT))` will do.